# How to wrap all existing files of github repo into one folder?

Tags: git, github, next.js

i am little confused about github because my current github repo looks like this [image]

and i want to wrap all this existing code file in client folder and also create new folder server and then push both folder to same existing repo

like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question is here exactly, just move the files:

```
mkdir client
git mv * .env.example .eslintrc client/ # skip .gitignore file
git commit -m 'Moved files to client directory'
```